# How to save NVIDIA X Server Settings (nvidia-settings)?

Tags: release-freya, settings, nvidia

I had changed resolution of the monitor from 75Hz to 60Hz and clicked a button "Save to X Configuration File" and saved into /ets/X11/xorg.conf as administrator. After restarting I still see 75Hz instead of 60Hz.

Comment: Why do you want a lower refresh rate

Comment: It sounds weird but while monitor is using 75Hz my atom-editor looks ugly. I mean I can see something like "blinking waves" on its background, but after changing resolution on a fly they disappear.

Comment: SOLVED | In my case this fixed it. [org -> gnome -> settings-daemon -> plugins -> xrandr | uncheck active](http://askubuntu.com/a/68487/412025)